# Copy row based on content and paste it in different sheets which are selected based on the content of the row

Tags: vba, excel

We've created a order sheet for all our machines, the main sheet is 'Order Sheet'.
And we're sending this sheet to the purchasing department at the end of the day.
When we run the macro to email the file, we wanted the macro to also copy each row to the specific machine worksheet. Eg. rows marked as 'Slicer' to go to the 'Slicer' sheet, 'blender' to 'blender', etc.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Sub PrintToNetwork()

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("A2:N25").Font.Size = 11
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Print & Send the sheet?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Empty Sheet")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Retail Order Sheet"
            .Body = "Hi Andy, Please order."
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Range("A1:N25").Select
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$N$25"
        oldprinter = Application.ActivePrinter

        For i = 0 To 15
           curNePrint = Format(i, "00")
           On Error Resume Next
              Application.ActivePrinter = "\\10.17.0.9\CCFN_Retail_MFP_BW on Ne" & curNePrint & ":"
        Next i

        ActiveWindow.Selection.PrintOut Copies:=1
        Application.ActivePrinter = oldprinter
        On Error GoTo 0
     Else

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of the macro you are using ? Where are the words located in the spreadsheet (column ?)

Comment: Hi Mitch the macro is a bit long to fit in the comments, but basically i'm printing the ''order sheet'' to a network printer and after it attaches the file to an email. The words are located in the second column.

Comment: Ok, is it always A2:N25 ? Is there anything on the other sheets already ? If so, then the info is appended to the end ?

Comment: Yes Mitch, the other sheets already have info on them, we'd want to add to the bottom of the sheet. The range on the ''order sheet'' is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rows' location on the destination worksheet is determined by examining the same column as the one containing the worksheet names, something like the following might do the trick. 
The `DispatchRows` sub scans `prngWorksheetNames`, looking for worksheets that exist by name.

You must call `DispatchRows` by passing it the range containing the worksheet names. For example, if the source worksheet names are on worksheet Summary, range C2:C50, you'd call `DispatchRows ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("C2:C50")`.

```
Option Explicit

'Copies entire rows to worksheets whose names are found within prngWorksheetNames.
'ASSUMPTION: on the destination worksheet, a copied row is appended at the lowest empty spot in the same column as prngWorksheetNames.
Public Sub DispatchRows(ByVal prngWorksheetNames As Excel.Range)
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rngWorksheetName As Excel.Range
    Dim sDestWorksheetTabName As String
    Dim oDestWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim bScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim bEnableEvents As Boolean

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    bScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    bEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For lRow = 1 To prngWorksheetNames.Rows.Count
        Set rngWorksheetName = prngWorksheetNames.Cells(lRow, 1)
        sDestWorksheetTabName = CStr(rngWorksheetName.Value)

        If TryGetWorksheetByTabName(ThisWorkbook, sDestWorksheetTabName, oDestWs) Then
            'Make sure there are no active autofilters on the destination worksheet, as they would typically interfere with the copy operation.
            If oDestWs.FilterMode Then
                oDestWs.ShowAllData
            End If

            'Copy and paste.
            rngWorksheetName.EntireRow.Copy
            oDestWs.Cells(oDestWs.Rows.Count, prngWorksheetNames.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next

Cleanup:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngWorksheetName = Nothing
    Set oDestWs = Nothing
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = bEnableEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdating
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub

'Returns True, and a reference to the target worksheet, if worksheet psName is found by name on pwbkHost.
Public Function TryGetWorksheetByTabName(ByVal pwbkHost As Excel.Workbook, ByVal psName As String, ByRef pshtResult As Excel.Worksheet) As Boolean
    Set pshtResult = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set pshtResult = pwbkHost.Worksheets(psName)

    TryGetWorksheetByTabName = Not pshtResult Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked a treat. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple script to achieve what you want. Insert in your code appropriately, or call it from your macro. I tested this many times to make sure it works.

```
Sub CopyLines()
 Dim mySheet
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim LastShtRow As Long
 Dim j

 LastRow = Sheets("Order Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For j = 2 To LastRow Step 1

    mySheet = Range("B" & j).Value
    LastShtRow = Sheets(mySheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A" & j & ":" & "N" & j).Copy

    Sheets(mySheet).Range("A" & LastShtRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Next j

 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```